# Shouldn't be these warnings with g++ -Wall?

Tags: c++, gcc-warning

I was just curious if the following code should result in warning or not by g++ compiler:

```
// Snip #1
bool x = 0;
x++;

// Snip #2
switch (x) {
default:
    printf("hi\n");
}
```

The problem is such statements exist in a legacy code i work upon :-|, I guess there should be some warnings for these?

I have g++-4.4.3c

Comment: What warnings are you expecting?  Tossing a warning in case 2 for "unused variable x" is touchy because, for all the compiler knows, there *were* cases in that switch, but the preprocessor ate them.

Comment: correct. that rules out the second.

Comment: If you had a really good compiler it would warn you that incrementing a bool is a deprecated language feature.

Comment: http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incrementing a bool is a deprecated function, yet it is still valid and achieves the desired result, therefore a warning should not appear, it is just bad practice to do so.

Answer (score 1):

With gcc, -Wall does not actually turn on all warnings.  The man page will cover all your options, but to be really thorough, use "-Wall -Weff-c++ -pedantic -Werror".